# VBA Regular Expression to return ALL matching patterns

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to break apart contact details that having been captured - we should have one entry per contact method but users are mashing in several to one box. I have two UDF (based on around the same basic script found here - https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/udf-to-extract-phone-numbers-from-cell-content.1045305/) that pull out the first email address and phone number within the text string, however I would like to pull out ALL the strings that match the patterns.

I thought I could call matches(X).Value to draw the X hit but even when I have multiple values in a string my matches.count only returns 1.

So the string "02012345678                01234123456                  FAKEMAIL@GMAIL.COM" will drop out 02012345678 but I would like to pull both numbers out, as well as being able to count them.

Note that due to the data being entered into a simple text field literally anything can, and has, gone in. We are looking to change things around this but that will take time, and training will only get us so far.

The full code I am using for phone numbers is below.

```
Private regexPhone As Object

Public Function GetPhoneNumberFromText(inputString As String) As String
    
    Dim matches As Object
    
    ' Set default value - blank in this case but could be "Not Found" or similar
    GetPhoneNumberFromText = ""
    
    ' Set up the regular expression first time around
    If regexPhone Is Nothing Then
        Set regexPhone = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regexPhone.Pattern = "(?:\+[0-9]{3})?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{5})"
        regexPhone.Global = False
        
        
    End If
    
    ' Get the matches
    Set matches = regexPhone.Execute(inputString)
    
    ' Quit if we can't find a number
    If matches.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ' Just process the first match
    'GetPhoneNumberFromText = regex.Replace(matches(0).Value, "$1$2$3")
    GetPhoneNumberFromText = matches(0).Value
    
    End Function
```

Comment: You have set `regexPhone.Global = False`   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_reg_expressions.htm#:~:text=A%20Boolean%20property%20that%20represents%20if%20the%20regular%20expression%20should%20be%20tested%20against%20all%20possible%20matches%20in%20a%20string.%20If%20not%20specified%20explicitly%2C%20Global%20value%20is%20set%20to%20False.

Comment: Many thanks - That solves it mostly. I need to build some looping into it for when there are more than a few matches but that really helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams pointed out I had set the global to false, which meant that only the first match was found... hence my issue.
Thanks - that has solved my main problem.